# Invoking functions using a function pointer approach

Tags: python, python-2.x, hash-map

I re-used this answer from this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2283243/5291015) to simulate a function pointer approach available in high-level languages like C.

While using this approach in Python, the dictionary I am defining to map the functions needs to be defined after all the functions are defined before. It makes the dictionary definition to be the last segment of the code, which doesn't look neat.

Is there a way like in C to export all the functions beforehand, so that I can define the mapping dictionary in the beginning? (See examples below). Or what would be the most pythonic approach to do this?

Below is my sample snippet of the code using the approach.

File-1 - `a1.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from a2 import *

def arithmeticOps():
    doOps('add',6,1)
    doOps('mul',6,4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arithmeticOps()
```

and File-2 - `a2.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def doOps(op, arg1, arg2):
    arithDict[op](arg1,arg2)

def doAdd(arg1, arg2):
    print "Sum =",arg1 + arg2

def doProd(arg1, arg2):
    print "Prod =",arg1 * arg2

arithDict = {
    'add': doAdd,
    'mul': doProd
}
```

I am able to run this code peacefully in Python 2.7, and it gives me the result I need.

```
# python a1.py 
Sum = 7
Prod = 24
```

I agree the built-in functions for addition (or) product could be used here, but the problem is for a bigger scale when I have custom functions in place.

Comment: Sample/prototype code is difficult to meaningfully review, in the future it's best to post your actual implementation. I hope you get useful answers though.

Comment: @Phrancis: I used this code to demo a full _working_ code to suit my purpose, but I still don't understand why it deserved a -ve vote

Comment: I suggest to look over [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for reference. This site is not quite like Stack Overflow, where minimal examples are preferred.

Comment: Whilst this code does run, it's not code you'd actually use. "sample snippet" imo is just another way to say example code. And the worst part about this, is unless we review your code in a specific way, then any answers we write for will be a waste of everyone's time. And so I've voted to close this as example code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You don't have to define your own functions for these arithmetic operations. These functions already exist in the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) module.

  ```
  from operator import add, mul

  operations = {
      'add': add,
      'mul': mul
  }
  ```
- In Python [snake-case is preferred](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) over camelCase for variable names.
- Don't use [`import *`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id23) imports. Import only the items you need. `import *` based imports can be helpful in shell for debugging and you may sometimes see them in a package's `__init__.py` to help define a clean [public API](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#public-and-internal-interfaces).

---

> Is there a way like in C to export all the functions before-hand, so
>   that I can define the mapping dictionary in the beginning (See
>   examples below). Or what would be the most pythonic approach to do
>   this?

There's no way to import only functions. The pythonic way is to import only the functions you need not everything.

> It makes the dictionary definition to be the last segment of the code
>   which doesn't look neat.

The dictionary approach is recommended in Python as there's no switch statement in Python and it's better than a bunch of `if-elif-else`. You could also create the dict in `a1.py` based on the imported functions. Though I don't find its definition in `a2.py` okay.

Another option can be to fetch the functions from `a2` module object itself if they can be re-named `add`, `mul` etc. This way you won't need a dict.

```
import a2

def arithmeticOps():
    getattr(a2, 'add')(6, 1)
    getattr(a2, 'mul')(6, 4)
```

Comment: That's a valid point true, the reason I asked this was for a more bigger scale. The functions `add`, `mul` are just for reference, I intend to use some custom functions with the approach. The example is just a prototype.

Comment: @Inian If your real code is different than what you posted, then, by all means, show us your real code. There is no point in posting MVCE here as it can raise concerns that you don't have to deal with in your real code (such as the `operator` module here). See also  [Why is hypothetical example code off-topic for CR?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1709/41243)

Comment: @MathiasEttinger: It is _logically_ one and the same, it just serves the same purpose. I removed my question earlier yesterday for not stating the working code. But here I have demonstrated a clear _working_ code asking for an enhancement, but still garnered a -ve vote

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a dispatcher here as you know the names of the functions you want to call in the end. So you'd be better off calling them directly. This also means that the `doOps` and `arithDict` are not necessary. Which in turn makes me question the use of splitting the code in two files.

Instead I’d write:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2


def do_add(arg1, arg2):
    print "Sum =", arg1 + arg2


def do_mult(arg1, arg2):
    print "Prod =", arg1 * arg2


def arithmetic_operations():
    do_add(6, 1)
    do_mult(6, 4)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arithmetic_operations()
```

or even simpler:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

print "Sum = 7"
print "Prod = 24"
```